# How long is it safe to store new tires before they degrade in quality?

Tags: tire, storage

I bought some road tires that were made for flat resistance, but within two months, the sidewalls on both got damaged to the point where I was getting repeated blowouts. I wrote to the manufacturer, and they were kind enough to send me a replacement pair.

In the meantime, I bought some new flat resistant tires to replace the busted ones.

Now I have two new pairs of flat resistant tires, but I only have a use for one at a time. How long can I store a new pair before I have to worry about the material degrading, dry rot, etc.?

(not mentioning the brands here because I don't want to bash the manufacturer that sent me the replacement.)

Comment: Did you ask the manufacturer? Maybe they can give you info since they have to store tires themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the storage conditions. If kept at room temperature, not excessively humid or dry, and kept in the dark, they can be stored for a long time. Oftentimes for years.

Your best storage bet is to wrap them in plastic and stash them in the back of a closet. I've kept high-end tubulars for two years that way and that rubber is much more sensitive to storage/dry rot compared to puncture-resistant tires.

Comment: It also depends on the type of rubber that they are made out of. Non-vulcanized rubbers tend to improve with age while others tend to degrade. (http://velonews.competitor.com/2011/02/bikes-and-tech/hutchinson-pro-tour-tubular-and-the-benefits-of-aging_160921)

And Lennard Zinn on tire age: (http://velonews.competitor.com/2008/07/bikes-and-tech/technical-qa-with-lennard-zinn-are-old-tires-safe_79570)

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that if they're stored in a cool dark place, and, preferably, kept wrapped somehow, they should be good for ten years or so (though possibly less for gumwalls).  You need to keep them away from UV light, ozone, and stuff like fumes from a poorly vented heater.  (Also, any sort of petroleum fumes would be bad, so a garage is not ideal.)

Also try to store them in such a way that they won't be distorted too badly (though perfectly flat is not necessary).  Wrapping (spiral plastic wrap, eg) helps keep the nasty stuff away, and helps keep them from getting distorted.

Answer (score -1):

I got some 15 year old new tires I've had in my garage for years. I put them on my car last week and they're fine so far.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Jim. Such a short post should be made as a comment, when you have 50 [rep](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). Kindly

Comment: And observations that apply to automobile tires are not generally applicable to bike tires.

Comment: Even for automobile tires, you have to be [careful](http://www.edmunds.com/car-care/how-old-and-dangerous-are-your-tires.html). A bicycle tire is quite different.